# How to destroy a tkinter figure each time it is updated?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plot

I am continuously plotting a matplotlib plot in realtime using tkinter. It is updated every 10 seconds with new data that is 610 samples per second. If I let this run for several hours, I eventually run out of memory (error shown below). How can I alter my code to flush the previous plots from memory?

error message here:

```
_tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk)

tdt_fs = 610
fs = 128
time_chunk = 10 # in seconds

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("real-time score (10s bin)")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 1,figsize = (10, 8))
frame1=Frame(root, bg = 'black')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

x_axis = np.linspace(0,time_chunk,time_chunk*fs)
y_axis = np.zeros(time_chunk*fs)
ax0, = ax[0].plot(x_axis,y_axis, c = 'c', lw=0.5)
ax1, = ax[1].plot(x_axis,y_axis, c = 'm', lw=0.5)
ax2, = ax[2].plot(x_axis,y_axis, c = 'y', lw=0.5)
ax3, = ax[3].plot(x_axis,y_axis, c = 'w', lw=0.5)

ax0.set_xdata(x_axis)
ax1.set_xdata(x_axis)
ax2.set_xdata(x_axis)
ax3.set_xdata(x_axis)
ax0.set_ydata(scaled_CH1) # this is 10 seconds of buffered data
ax1.set_ydata(scaled_CH2) # this is 10 seconds of buffered data
ax2.set_ydata(scaled_CH3) # this is 10 seconds of buffered data
ax3.set_ydata(scaled_CH4) # this is 10 seconds of buffered data

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = frame1)  
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)

frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
prediction_label = Label(master = frame2, text = f"prediction: {pred_label}", font = ("Arial", 20), borderwidth = 3, relief = 'solid')
prediction_label.pack()

canvas.draw()
root.update()
canvas.flush_events()
prediction_label.destroy()

root.mainloop()
```

Should I simply clear the plot with ax.clear()?

Comment: Please [edit] this question into a [mre]. We can't run this code as-is because it's missing imports and data, among other things. We don't need your whole codebase, just enough to be able to run it and reproduce the issue. Also, what happens if you try `ax.clear()`?